# Data standardization or normalization in GBDT

Tags: cart, standardization, boosting

Is it necessary to do data normalization(standardization) before using gbdt?what effect does it have if I don't do that proprecessing?

Comment: @Sycorax, so there is no hurt if I used starndadization to transform the variables to be mean 0 and variance 1?

Comment: Scaling makes absolutely no difference.